# Splitting char into char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, substring

I do have a char string:

```
uint8_t word[40] = "a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d";
```

I need to somehow split it into char array, so it would look like this:

```
uint32_t hfFile[5];
hfFile[0] = 0xa9993e36;  
hfFile[1] = 0x4706816a;  
hfFile[2] = 0xba3e2571;  
hfFile[3] = 0x7850c26c;  
hfFile[4] = 0x9cd0d89d;
```

Later i want to check, is other array elements equal to the hfFile's elements.

My problem is, I don't know how to extract exact portions from char string, and how will it work, if

```
another_array[0] = 0xa9993e36;
```

look like this?

Comment: Why you are using C-Style string instead of the C++ String?

Comment: working with chars is faster then with strings, and i need my code to be as fast as possible

Comment: How are you going to use this? Do you need copies or only views of the data?

Comment: Good question from Bob. If your performance requirements are so stringent that you cannot afford 50,000 `std::strings` (which can probably be done in under a millisecond on decent modern hardware!) then you might want to avoid the copies altogether, and just directly index the original data when needed.

Comment: What's the type of hfFile? Your example direct assignment isn't legal c++

Comment: @Caleth: uint32_t, which is unsigned int

Comment: Note that `'0' != 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and then, you can use [`string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to do this:

```
std::string word = "a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d";
std::string hfFile[5]; // or use std::vector instead of C-array
hfFile[0] = word.substr(0, 8);
hfFile[1] = word.substr(8, 16);
hfFile[2] = word.substr(16, 24);
hfFile[3] = word.substr(24, 32);
hfFile[4] = word.substr(32, 40);
```

And then the comparison can be as simple as this:

```
if(hfFile[0] == "a9993e36")
    std::cout << "equal\n";
```

---

Following the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) approach won't hurt performance. Compile with optimization flags and you will be fine. I suspect you are a victim of premature optimization here.

Comment: Is there any possible way avoiding using strings? I want to keep code as low-level as it possible, operating with chars only

Comment: @Yokz: Why's that

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: it's a little part of the algorythm, and this part is gonna be used like 50000 times or more, thus i want to keep it as fast as possible

Comment: A `std::string` should be plenty fast. Don't abandon sensible tools that make your code simple and easy to prove, unless you _know_ that you have to. 50,000 isn't very many times.

Comment: @Yokz: See here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b78a755a63f072e5 There is a sizeable difference in terms of percent, but the overall execution time is still extremely low.

Comment: How does comparing a std::string and an integer work? For me gcc won't compile it.

Comment: @user3109672: It's just a missing set of `"`, obviously.

Comment: there's no "0x" in the original string either

Comment: this is lacking some `std::stou`, which is likely the slowest part

Comment: Changing second parameter in every substr to 8 did what i wanted, thanks for help!

Comment: When you include the conversion from text to number, the c++ way is faster: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62aa39e2493d0a2b

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
int length = strlen(word);

for(int i = 0; (i*8) < length; i++)
{
    strncpy(hfFile[i], word + i*8, 8);
}
```

And if you want to compare those hfFile strings with `another_array[0] = "0xa9993e36"` you can do it like so:

```
if(strncmp(hfFile[0], another_array[0] + 2, 8) == 0) ...
```

The `+2` is used to skip `0x` at the beginning of `another_array`

Please note that this code does not contain any error checking.

Please also note that I recommend using `std::string` instead of C-style strings!

Comment: 6 or 8? I didn't do the math ;p

Comment: @gsamaras: Well I think it should be correct because if `i` is 1 I copy from `word + i*8` which starts at char 8. Or which Problem do you see?

Comment: @gsamaras: Huh? Eight bytes are copied at a time. This is basic arithmetic.

Comment: @gsamaras `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) hfFile[i/8][i%8] = word[i];` would also work but ugh

Comment: Such an overkill, but you are right @BoundaryImposition. =)